# How to add user control on run time in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

How do I add a user control on page load dynamically in ASP.NET?

I have a div with `ID="contentData"` and few controls

- one.ascx
- two.ascx
- three.ascx

Now I have created a page `default.aspx`, which may get parameters in query string, in one of the following ways:

```
default.aspx?val=one  
default.aspx?val=two  
default.aspx?val=three
```

I am taking the value from

```
Request.QueryString["val"]
```

Now how do I load specific control in this?

```
<div ID="controlData"></div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your aspx

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">

</div>
```

In Page_Load

```
    UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("test.ascx");
    div1.Controls.Add(uc);
```

All you need to do is make your div server bound by adding runat="server", and in the codebehind use Page.LoadControl to go out and fetch your usercontrol and then add it to your div using the div's Controls.Add

Comment: maybe also replace that div with a Panel, for easier mapping with an instance on the server (in some cases VS doesn't automatically generate a member when runat=server is added to html elements). Build the path to ascx based on the value from query. Validate or wrap in try-catch; handle non-existing. For universal control placement, build the path by starting with "~" character (e.g. "~/controls/" + this.Request.QueryString["val"] + ".ascx") - but, again, validate the value from query.

Comment: I second validating the value from query.

Comment: After reading these answers and some articles i am now able to do something better, Page_Init() is the function in which i have to apply the code, but do i  need to write code in !Page.IsPostBack ? if yes the why this function is user?

Answer (score 3):

```
// Load the User Control

Control uc = LoadControl("~/MyUserControl.ascx");

// Add the User Control to the Controls collection

Page.Controls.Add(uc);
```

for more details go thru this link - [An Extensive Examination of User Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms972975(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972975.aspx

Also do read the use of ~ tidle in .net
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the Page's LoadControl method to do this programmatically:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf.aspx

Also, if your intention is to add it to the div, make sure you make that div a server control by adding runat="server" in the markup

Comment: ... or use an [ASP.NET Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx), which is essentially the same as a div with `runat=server`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear what you're asking, so forgive me if this doesn't answer the question.

Assuming the possible values are known in advance and that the number is modest -- like the three in your example -- the easiest thing to do is to include all the controls on the form with "visible=false", then in your Load method set visible to true on the one you want.

If the number of possibilities is very large, or if it is dynamic so that you don't even know what the possibilities are at coding time, then you could put in a wrapper object, say a div, and add the items to its "controls" property. But I'd avoid this if at all possible because it would be very hard to maintain: future programmers won't even know what controls could possibly be on the screen.

Comment: No data is dynamic and will load from DB so i can't afford to load and visible false...