# replacing usercontrol1 with usercontrol2 in the same placeholder of the aspx page, with the button in usercontrol1

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am able to replace user controls in the same placeholder with the buttons in main aspx page..
But how can i replace the user controls in the same placeholder with the button in usercontrol..

For example i have usercontrol1 loaded and with a button inside the control i want to change to usercontrol2 in the same placeholder..

so i have usercontrol1 with buttons for usercontrol2 and usercontrol3
i have usercontrol2 with buttons for usercontrol1 and 3
& i have usercontrol3 with buttons for usercontrol1 and 2..

and i would like to move between theses controls..with the buttons in the control

Answer (score 0):

Add event handlers in your usercontrols and use the [usercontrol's click events](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33874/Capture-Button-s-Click-Event-of-User-Control-in-th) on the page accordingly (by hiding/unhiding the other controls or [creating runtime control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069347/how-to-add-user-control-on-run-time-in-asp-net-solved)).

Comment: I am able to capture the clickevent.. but it shows object not found for the placeholder..

Comment: and one thing i realised that usercontrol's click events you have mentioned is for static controls.. when using dynamic controls we do not drag and put it in aspx file.. we call it on a button click outside the place holder.. and on next click placeholder is cleared and filled with new control. Now i have a control with a button which is suppose to call new control.. then since the value of control is dynamic i can not create a event in aspx for the button in control.... Now is there a way that i can register mycontrol on aspx page to write events for button inside the control.

Comment: Sure u can.. Since u r using dynamic usercontrols, u should recreate ur controls on every request(postback) as there is no viewstate saved for dynamic controls and hence they disappear on postback. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914692/events-in-my-dynamically-loaded-user-controls-do-not-fire-in-asp-net-web-applica
Alternatively, u can put those 3 controls in the same placeholder(static) and toggle visibility.